# Collapse all before expanding in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have buttons that expands and collapses divs. And I need to add some javascript that collapses all expanded ones before expanding the one.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-secondary"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#resize-form"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="resize-form" title="Resize">
    Resize
 </button>     
 
 <button class="btn btn-secondary"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#brightness-form"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="resize-form" title="Resize">
    Brightness
 </button>     
 
 <div id="resize-form" class="collapse bg-primary p-4" style="background: red">
    <p>Resize</p>
 </div>
  <div id="brightness-form" class="collapse bg-secondary p-4">
   <p>
    Brightness
  </p>
 </div>
```

Whats needed to collapse all open ones before expanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   $(function() {
       $("button").click(function(){
           $(".collapse").removeClass("show");
         });            
   });
</script>
```